# How to use asynchronous methods (JSON Restful services) in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, synchronization

I have an `iOS` application that `sync` data from a `JSON` restful `web service`. This method is called from an external class (not `UI controller`). This class has a sync method and It sends and retrieves data without any problem. My problem is how do I pause the UI till I get my result.

The following would provide the idea  about the code.

UIController Class

```
let C : Customer = Customer(UserName: UserName!, Password: Password!)
let S : Syncronization = Syncronization()
S.Sync(C)
```

Syncronization class

```
Class Syncronization : NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate

func Sync(C : Customer){
        var datastr = ""
        datastr = "http://192.168.248.134:8008/MobileWeb.svc/GetFirstTimeSync/" + C.UserName + "/" + C.Password
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: datastr)!
        self.buffer = NSMutableData()
        let defaultConfigObject:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let req:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url).resume()
    }

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        print("Recieved with data")
        buffer.appendData(data)
    }

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
            if error == nil {
                print("Download Successful")
                print("Done with Bytes " + String(buffer.length))
                self.parseJSONA(self.buffer)
            }
            else  {
                print("Error %@",error!.userInfo);
                print("Error description %@", error!.localizedDescription);
                print("Error domain %@", error!.domain);
            }
    }

    func parseJSONA(data:NSMutableData) {
         do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! Array<AnyObject>
        } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
   }
```

I have tried dispacther methods, but I believe I do not know how to use that so far cause most of the examples have down the services & data exchange on UI Controllers.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by pause the UI, and why do you want to do this? you can disable elements of the UI while it's being synced by setting the element's `enabled:Bool` to `false`

Comment: @mmarkman It's just that when I call that method. I want to wait till I get the result, cause I want to use those data to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to do something in your UI based on the outcome of your call to `S.Sync(C)`

One way of doing that is to include a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) as a parameter to your `Sync` function.

Here's how I would do that (Disclaimer...I haven't checked everything in a compiler, so there might be errors along the way. See how far you get, and if there are problems, just write again :-)):

```
enum SynchronizationResult {
    case Success(Array<AnyObject>)
    case Failure(NSError)
}

class Syncronization : NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    var functionToExecuteWhenDone: ((SynchronizationResult) -> Void)?

    func Sync(C : Customer, callback: (SynchronizationResult) -> Void){
        functionToExecuteWhenDone = callback
        var datastr = ""
        datastr = "http://192.168.248.134:8008/MobileWeb.svc/GetFirstTimeSync/" + C.UserName + "/" + C.Password
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: datastr)!
        self.buffer = NSMutableData()
        let defaultConfigObject:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let req:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        req.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        session.dataTaskWithURL(url).resume()
     }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        print("Recieved with data")
        buffer.appendData(data)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        if error == nil {
            print("Download Successful")
            print("Done with Bytes " + String(buffer.length))
            self.parseJSONA(self.buffer)
        } else  {
            print("Error %@",error!.userInfo);
            print("Error description %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            print("Error domain %@", error!.domain);
            let result = SynchronizationResult.Failure(error!)
            if let functionToExecuteWhenDone = functionToExecuteWhenDone {
                functionToExecuteWhenDone(result)
            }
        }
    }

    func parseJSONA(data:NSMutableData) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! Array<AnyObject>
            let result = SynchronizationResult.Success(json)
            if let functionToExecuteWhenDone = functionToExecuteWhenDone {
                functionToExecuteWhenDone(result)
            }
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             let result = SynchronizationResult.Failure(error)
             if let functionToExecuteWhenDone = functionToExecuteWhenDone {
                 functionToExecuteWhenDone(result)
             }
         }
     }
}
```

So...we introduce an Enum called SynchronizationResult to handle the outcome of fetching data.

We then add a function to be called when done, as a parameter to the `Sync` function:

`func Sync(C : Customer, callback: (SynchronizationResult) -> Void)`

This method will be called with a `SynchronizationResult` as a parameter and returns void.

We store that callback in `functionToExecuteWhenDone` for later usage.

Depending on whether you see any errors along the way or everything is sunshine, we generate different `SynchronizationResult` values along the way and call your `functionToExecuteWhenDone` with the current `SynchronizationResult` when we are ready (when parsing is done or we have failed)

And in your ViewController you'd do something along the lines of

```
let C : Customer = Customer(UserName: UserName!, Password: Password!)
let S : Syncronization = Syncronization()
S.Sync(C) { (result) in
    switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
            //Your code to update UI based on json goes here
        case .Failure(let error):
            //Your code to handle error goes here
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and is what you needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the Sync class a completion handler closure.

In your `UIViewController`:

```
S.completion = {
 information in
 UIElement.updateWith(information)
}
```

and of course you'll need to add a member to your `Syncronization` class:

`var completion:((information:String)->())!`

and you can call `completion("here's some info!")` from inside `parseJSON()` or `URLSession()` of the `Syncronization` class

[Here's some reading on closures in Swift](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)

Comment: Yeah but how do I udpate ui from external class

Comment: put the `S.completion = { information in button.text = information }` right before the `S.Sync()` call in the `UIViewController`

Comment: There is no such a method name s.completeion...!

Answer (score 2):

this might help you
https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

    // do downloading or sync task here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // update some UI with downloaded data/sync data

    }
}
```

Comment: how do I hold the sync class so that I will get the JSON data to the method?

Answer (score 1):

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    print("This is run on the background queue")

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    })
})
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056205/how-to-use-background-thread-in-swift)

Comment: how do I hold the sync class so that I will get the JSON data to the method?

Comment: just add the tasks you want to perform in the background here: print("This is run on the background queue")

Comment: I understand that it's alright. Method is working only with the internal methods. How do I stop till I get data from server? print("This is run on the main queue... executed before I get the data from server