# Swift save user Coordinates while navigating to other views

Tags: swift

In my project the user can choose to save their coordinates to firebase json. I currently using tab bars as my main navigation. What is the best approach to continue to save  their gps even when they are navigating to other view controllers in the app.

Comment: You may use a background thread to regularly update your database. See [How to use background thread in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056205/how-to-use-background-thread-in-swift)

Comment: Is your Project an IOS Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a locationManager singleton, it can handle all your location methods instead of placing it in a viewController ;)

And if you want to save your user position locally, you can use NSUserDefault, or CoreData, or save it in your locationManager singleton if it's just for the session.

Comment: How does a locationManager solve the problem of continuously saving the location data? A locationManager is first and foremost a way how you organize your code / functionality.

Comment: I just think it's a good place to save data linked to location for the session and get them from anywhere in the app. Am I wrong ?

Comment: From the app design that makes sense. But just a singleton does not solve the problem. If you add that you start a background thread that periodically saves the location to your locationManager then it would be a solution.

Comment: Or you can just save your location in locationManager every time your locationManager userLocationUpdate method triggers.

Comment: You mean your locationManager implements the  `CLLocationManagerDelegate`?  Yes.