# Understanding dispatch queue threading

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am working on a project that collects (1000+) data points from a database and updates itself every few seconds. To keep my main thread from locking, I have to read, sort, and save data in a background thread. I would like to understand the difference between two background calls.

In this [article](https://medium.com/@gabriel_lewis/threading-in-swift-simply-explained-5c8dd680b9b2) the author gives us a good example of using a background thread like so: `DispatchQueue(label: "foo", qos: .utility).async {}`

In another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40997652/6553331) on this site, I found a great example of an extension of `DispatchQueue`. This one does not use a label.

I know these two methods are different but how exactly (other than one being an extension)? Second question: is it best practice to wait for a background thread activity to finish its job before calling it again? Or does that matter?

Comment: FYI - your question is not about "Swift" threading. It's about Grand Central Dispatch. The language doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only surface difference between the behavior of a dispatch queue that you make yourself (the first example) and a built-in `global` dispatch queue (the second example) is that the former is serial (by default) while the latter is concurrent.

> Second question: is it best practice to wait

It is *never* right to "wait". If you have multiple tasks to coordinate you can use GCD to do that (e.g. dispatch groups).

Answer (score 2):

I agree 100% with everything that [matt said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53489813/1271826) (+1).

A couple of additional observations:

1. As he said, the key difference is that global queues are concurrent queues, whereas when you create a queue, it defaults to being a serial queue. E.g. this is a serial queue:

   ```
   let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo", qos: .utility)
   ```

   You can, of course, create your own concurrent queue:

   ```
   let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "foo", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
   ```
2. Let's assume for a second that you decided that you really did want to use a concurrent queue. That then begs the question why you'd create your own named custom concurrent queue vs using one of the global queues. There are a few reasons:

   - You can see your custom queue names when debugging in Xcode and Instruments. E.g. here is a breakpoint where I can see which queue my breakpoint is on (as well as what other threads are being used by that queue, too):

     [image]
   - Certain more advanced techniques, such as barriers, can not be performed on global queues. For those narrow set of applications, you might want to use your own custom concurrent queue.