# background thread executes before main thread ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, ios13

I want to push a view controller and want rest tasks to work in the background without freezing UI. but either my UI freezes or background thread executes before. a small example of my work is attached.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
        }
        print("This is run on the background queue")
    }
```

Result:

```
This is run on the background queue
This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block
```

The main queue should have executed first than the background thread.

Comment: 1. Add `bigTasksTakingTimeInMinutes` method 2. you do not need `DispatchQueue.main.async` as you already in the main thread.

Comment: I think this will helps you to understand background thread usage -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056205/how-to-use-background-thread-in-swift

Comment: user ap, you'll have to start from the basics to work with threading.

Answer (score 5):

Your code basically executes like this:

```
// 1. Send this code off to the global queue to be processed async
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  // 3. You're here once the global queue decides it's ready to run this code

  // 4. Send this code off to the main queue to be processed async
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // 6. You're here once the main queue decides it's ready to run this code
    print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
  }

  // 5. This is now printed
  print("This is run on the background queue")
}

// 2. whatever happens here
```

The reason your code runs like this is that you're dispatching everything asynchronously. this means that all you do is pass the closure off to be executed by the targetted queue at a later time, or whenever it's ready. By using async you are telling the queue you don't want to wait for this.

If you'd want your main queue bit to run immediately, you can use `DispatchQueue.main.sync` instead. That will block the execution of the context you're in (in this case the `async` closure you passed to the global queue) until the closure you're running with `sync` is completed.

I would typically recommend to avoid `sync` unless you *really* need it because it's far too easy to make a queue wait for itself and be locked forever (deadlock).

Answer (score -4):

> Try adding a delay to your background tasks - to see what happens

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("This is run on the main queue")
    }

    longRunningFunction
    print("This is run on the background queue")
}


func longRunningFunction() {
    sleep(1)
}
```

Now you will see the output you expected.

Comment: Downvoted because it won't work if the main thread is just processing a lengthy operation.

Comment: right @gnasher729